# Four girls in a maze; find a match of their names and given numbers

Tags: lateral-thinking

***There are four girls in the maze.***

*1: One with dark hair and wearing a green hat. 

2: One with brown skin wearing a black tank top. 

3: One who hit the wall and bloodied her head. 

4: One who ran along the path and hurt her leg.*

***Their names are Hazel, Azalea, Cathy and Ellie.***

A. Hazel found a way out while taking Ellie in her arms.
B. Azalea was left behind with Cathy.
C. Hazel has a hat in her hand but it's not hers.
D. Cathy screamed out loud for help at the sight of blood.

---

> Question: Which number (1-4) matches with which name?

---

Hope this is not too easy, or weird. Please help me improve this question if you have any ideas.

Thanks for visiting to see this post!

Hint:

> They all know each other and were together in a maze finding a way out

Comment: In the title you ask "what did they face"? Is this relevant to the answer? Do we need to identify some monster?

Comment: Hi @Fillet Sorry for that: cos I'm a novice n not from English speaking country. Now I have it changed.

Comment: Now this is [On Hold], is it going to be [Closed]?

Why? I can't tell you more; if I tell you guys more, that will just be the answers...

Comment: It is always difficult to judge a puzzle without knowing the answer, see http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2885/voting-on-surface-appearance . Maybe some kind of hint is possible? Could you hightlight part of the puzzle that is particularly relevant?

Comment: Questions can be reopened by the users who voted to put it on-hold or by other users: see  http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions and http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions

Comment: From a reader's perspective, this looks like you've made up a story, given us some facts from it and expect us to reconstruct the story. That's something that works fine in person where people can ask questions to narrow things down, but doesn't really fit well on a site like SE. This is partly because you've given us a lot of things that happened but no statements about things that definitely didn't happen - who's to say that all the girls didn't have hats?

Comment: Now, it's possible that there's some trick outside the actual statements that's meant to better define the solution. For example, the situation is actually easier to explain if all the numbered statements applied to Ellie (although the wording of the question doesn't really work with that). It's hard to know whether that sort of thing exists without at least a general statement that people are going about things the wrong way, though.

Comment: For those who make this OnHold and let it Closed though I edited and edited several time, I'd like to explain this puzzle's answer as following. (I know what @Zandar mean but this can not express any more hints as this is puzzle; and it's made by non-english speaker.)

Comment: According to A. Ellie is 4.
According to B. and D. it is Azalea with strained blood so she is 3.
According to C. Hazel is not 1. So she is 2.
Only Cathy and no. 1 left, so Cathy is 1.
I just created for simple but don't get why it is going too broad, and thanks for closing/onhold this @ just the day it was uploaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel like the answer you're looking for is

> 1:Cathy, 2 Hazel, 3 Azalea, 4 Ellie

because

> Azalea was left behind with Cathy, Cathy screamed at blood, presumably not her own, so Azalea is 3. Hazel and Ellie got out, with Hazel supporting Ellie, since Ellie needed support, she's 4. That leaves 1 and 2 for Hazel and Cathy. Hazel doesn't have a hat, so she's not 1. Cathy 1, Hazel 2, Azalea 3, Ellie 4

However. this is not a logic puzzle:

> These are all leaps of 'logic', and there's no purely logical 'solution' to this riddle. Seeing as Hazel has a hat that's not hers (or her partners) also implies that all 4 have had contact, which opens up the whole thing, and leads to the more logical conclusion that 1:Azalea, 2 Hazel, 3 Ellie, 4 Cathy, seeing as you're more likely to support someone that has hurt her leg, instead of carrying them.

Comment: Hi @DrunkWolf, I edited and remove tag: Logic Puzzle. Sorry if I missed out smth as it hard to make puzzle in english since I am not from English speaking country. 

Thanks for your guess but two names are not right. Pls see my edited question again!? :)

Comment: @Nai I guess with the edit Ellie is one of the hurt ones, seeing as she's carried she's probably the one that bumped her head, as someone with a hurt leg would only have to be supported. So 1:Azalea, 2 Hazel, 3 Ellie, 4 Cathy. The thing is though, with this puzzle, a lot of the work isn't "what is the puzzle telling us", but more "guess what the maker was thinking". That's fine and all, but not really what the site aims for, hence your question was tagged as to broad.  Lastly, no need to apologise! We like new people that make an effort!

Comment: If 3 is Ellie, why did Cathy scream out at the sight of blood; as it is only Cathy and Azalea left? 
You still missed out smth, pls read carefully to my questions again!? 
I asked to my friends (without telling that's made by me) and they got the answer.

Comment: @Nai True i would've guessed it correctly if i had read it better the second time. 1:Cathy, 2 Hazel, 3 Azalea, 4 Ellie. That said, the question says 'Cathy got left behind with Azalea', that implies they've had contact with the others, so she could've seen blood literally anywhere. And that's exactly what i mean, these steps are logical to `you`.

Comment: @Nai edited with the reasoning.